# A button do thing on clicking & undo it on another click

Tags: javascript, wordpress

**Hello,**

**I want to achieve the following:**

When Button is clicked CSS Style changes to display: block on second click must be changed to display: none. And it must be looped

**How to achieve that?**

I managed to create this code which adds css style when clicked(but I can't make second click event):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button'); button.addEventListener('click', () => { const element = document.querySelector('div.wpcs_price_info ul'); element.setAttribute('style', 'display:block !important'); });
```

Comment: So write the function to examine the element you want to toggle between 'none' and 'block,' if it's in one state then update it to the other. You're effectively looking for toggle functionality, and I'm pretty sure there must be an example on here somewhere already.

Comment: How is the loop part supposed to work after the second click (that changes display to none)? The user will not be able to click the button after that point.

Comment: it's not possible to click second time button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy, just add a if condition.

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let shown = false;
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const element = document.querySelector("div.wpcs_price_info ul");
    if (shown) {
        element.setAttribute("style", "display:none !important");
        shown = false;
    } else {
        element.setAttribute("style", "display:block !important");
        shown = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I used that code but still not working, it's showing on first click but on second click nothing happens

Comment: oh sorry, i fotget to let the shown change

Comment: @Gelebrin7 i have already modified the answer

Comment: There is one problem, same css class has many objects and it's applies only for first one not others. How to solve this?